# Using a .join to return `|` in between multiple values

Tags: javascript, ejs

Upon a search I am rendering a bunch of different data, however, sometimes the search result is associated with multiple categories. I want to be able to add a  |  between the category names when there are more than one. Any advice on how to do this using `.join`?

I have tried a number of different things, and have not been able to figure it out.

Copy of my EJS template is below

```
div class="grid">
  <div class="template">
          <div class="Countries">
              <img alt="" src="/public/icons/ <%= country.icons %>" /> <%= country.name %>
          </div>
  
          <div class ="Category">

          <% country.categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>
              <%= cat.name %>
          <% }); %>
    
          </div>
   </div>
```

EDIT re: comments
[image]

Comment: what is your templating language?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am using EJS...

Comment: Just replace your `country.categories.forEach` block with `<%= country.categories.join('|') %>`?

Comment: ```<% country.categories.join('|')(function(cat){ %>``` @Nick This doesn't look right...

Comment: @ggorlen Nope..

Comment: @KyleUSA no, replace the entire `forEach` block with that code

Comment: @Nick but then `cat` becomes undefined it says...

Comment: @KyleUSA replace *all* of `<% country.categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>
              <%= cat.name %>
          <% }); %>`

Comment: @Nick So that works better but then I lose the values themselves. Please see screen shot I added to the post.. thanks for all your help!

Comment: @KyleUSA sorry, didn't look closely enough at your code, you need `<%= country.categories.map(cat=>cat.name).join('|') %>`

Comment: @Nick You are a god amongst men/women. Thanks! Throw an answer up and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the list of names separated by `|`, remove the `forEach` block:

```js
<% country.categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>
    <%= cat.name %>
<% }); %>
```

and replace it with a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) from the individual objects to their `name` property, which values can then be [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ed:

```js
<%= country.categories.map(cat=>cat.name).join('|') %>
```